# hibernate @ElementCollection and Embeded

Tags: java, hibernate

i have three classes :

```
@Embeddable
public class A  {
    private List<String> refs;
    @ElementCollection
    public List<String> getRefs() {
        return refs;
    }

    public void setRefs(List<String> refs) {
        this.refs = refs;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class B  {
    private A reference;

    @Embedded
    public A getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference(A reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
@Entity
public class C {
    private Long id;

    private List<B> glossaryReferenceList;
    private B mainNarrator;

    @Embedded
    public B getMainNarrator() {
        return mainNarrator;
    }

    public void setMainNarrator(B mainNarrator) {
        this.mainNarrator = mainNarrator;
    }

    @ElementCollection
    public List<B> getGlossaryReferenceList() {
        return glossaryReferenceList;
    }

    public void setGlossaryReferenceList(List<B> glossaryReferenceList) {
        this.glossaryReferenceList = glossaryReferenceList;
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

but hibernate cant handle it and on start up it throws `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

but either i remove

1. glossaryReferenceList property from C or
2. refs property form A

it gets solved and no exception is thrown during hibernate start up.( I mean just one of above changes solves the exception)

it looks that hibernate cant handle 3 level Embedded Objects

by the way a few moments age i have boon getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException:3` from the same source but i cant remember how did it change to `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

Can any body help? Am I right about Hibernate 3 level embedded object??
please help!

here is the detailed Exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:400)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:357)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1717)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1423)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 39 more
```

Comment: Nothing in that code should throw a ConcurrentModificationException.  Can you add the exception to your question, along with the code referred to by the exception stack trace?

Comment: Embedded inside embedded really smell. Why don't you use entities?

Comment: Same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359574/hibernate-throwing-concurrentmodificationexception-with-an-embedded-elementcolle

Answer (score 0):

Finally I gut the answer!
Two level of ElementCollection cant get Implemented as there should be a reference to it.